# How to change color on switch?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have 2 projects. In both I style switch. After updating VS I have problems in my new project when I add

```
  <Switch>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="On">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor"
                Value="#2D78FD" />
                            <Setter Property="OnColor"
                Value="#2D78FD" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Off">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor"
                Value="LightGray" />
                            <Setter Property="OnColor"
                Value="LightGray" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Switch>
```

I understand that I have problems with themes
On my phone I have Dark theme so I write

```
BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=White, Dark=White}"
```

And then I have white BackgroundColor and have problems with the switch
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKyPp.png)

If I don`t write

```
BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=White, Dark=White}"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQJY6.png)

Why my OnColor does not work at white BackgroundColor when it turns off(I tried other colors and only ThumbColor change color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your Xamarin.forms version to the latest `4.8.0.1364`, I test your code and it works well.

Comment: I have the latest version.I have the problem(it does not style switch) after updating to the latest version

Comment: @MariaKamenskyh Can you please check again if all your project has updated to the latest version. Here is my test sample project and you can check:  [switch-sample](https://github.com/XfHua/switch-sample).

Comment: I noticed that our projects are different.when I run my project, depending on the theme on the phone, the theme of the program is the same as on the project.I have a dark theme on the phone and because of this I have problems.When I run your project, no matter what theme I have on my phone, the theme of the program is still light.please tell me how to do the same?because if I write a white background or write a theme  BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=White, Dark=White}" then OnColor does not work for me

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on my side. Can you please share me a sample project which has this problem?

Comment: I edit the code in my project and all works well. Can you share me your project?